# Unable to grab attribute value having a space in attribute name using jsoup java instead getting empty string

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm new to jsoup and trying to grab the attribute value of "title data-original-title" attribute but getting an empty string. I want the value

> **Jul-30-2015 03:26:13 PM**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr style="border-color: #E1E1E1; border-width: 1px; background-color: #F9F9F9; border-top-style: solid;">
<th>Height</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>txn</th>
<th>Uncles</th>
<th>Miner</th>
<th>GasUsed</th>
<th>GasLimit</th>
<th>Avg.GasPrice</th>
<th>Reward</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td>
<td>
**<span rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Jul-30-2015 03:26:13 PM">1149 days 18 hrs ago</span>**
</td>
```

My code is

```
for (int i = total_pages; i >= 1; i--) {
            System.out.println("\nDisplaying blocks on page " + i);
            String newString = "https://etherscan.io/blocks?p=" + i;
            Document d3 = Jsoup.connect(newString).get();
            Elements e = d3.select("table.table-hover > tbody");
            Elements r = e.get(0).select("tr");

           for (Element cr : r) {
            Elements test = d3.select("span");
            System.out.println(test.attr("data-original-title"));

            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I modified the attribute value to get data placement value and it is being retrieved correctly. But the data-original-title still returns empty string.

Comment: Can you name (in your question) where exactly the error is, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data attributes are special kind of attributes so accessing them is a bit different but still very easy.
Instead of

```
System.out.println(test.attr("data-original-title"));
```

use:

```
System.out.println(test.first().dataset().get("original-title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to see if this works :

```
d3.select("span[data-original-title]").get(0).attr("data-original-title")
```

Explanation :

This looks for the first span containing attribute "data-original-title" and gets the value of that attribute.

Comment: It's giving index out of bound exception.

Comment: What is the url you are using to connect ? `newString` does not look like a url.

Comment: I have updated the code to include the entire for loop, including the url.

Comment: I just changed the attribute value from data-original-title to title and that solved my problem.

Comment: Check my answer to see how to properly handle data attributes.